# Installing gdal_retile?

Tags: python, gdal

I spent the whole day trying to install GDAL binding for Python. And now it seems to work. At least this import statement now does not produce any error messages:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

now I want to use [this](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html) creature, which is supposed for creating tiles.I tried two different ways:

```
import gdal_retile
```

and

```
from osgeo import gdal_retile
```

But they do not work.

How can I use this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdal_retile.py` is a Python script that makes use of the GDAL Python bindings but cannot be imported as a class or function. Depending on your GDAL version (>2.0) you can import most gdal utilities (`gdalwarp`, `gdal_translate`, ...) but not the Python scripts.

You can [look at the source code of `gdal_retile.py`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/77544764f51420e42468641fc3d5a087f8ea6d8f/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_retile.py) and pick out the functions you want to use and import them.

Alternatively you can call it as is (a command line utility) with `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

@Kersten is right. Create a folder with a custom [library](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/init-py-file/#:%7E:text=Any%20directory%20with%20an%20init,Import%20submodules) name. Copy gdal_retile.py into this folder. Within this folder, create any empty python file **init**.py.

```
mygdal
 __init__.py 
 my_gdal_retile.py
```

Start using this library in your code by importing it. The example below is for the simple task of generating tiles.

```
  from mygdal import my_gdal_retile
    from mygdal.my_gdal_retile import *
    import pandas as pd
    from osgeo import gdal
    command="gdal_retile.py  -ps 512 512 -overlap 128  \
           -targetDir  MyTiles  MyGeotiff.tif -v"    
    my_gdal_retile.main(command.split())
```